# Cosa significa "pretendendo alla nobiltà di una staffetta di lampade" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Il Gran Magro, giudicava i malati per annate, come un intenditore di vini o un maestro in pensione. Lo assecondavano essi, resistendo raramente alla Rocca per più di quattro stagioni. La durata media era quella, da un ottobre all'altro, il tempo di aggregarsi e imparare un linguaggio, consuetudini, un decalogo che valesse per tutti. Ciascuno, infine, quasi **pretendendo alla nobiltà di una staffetta di lampade**, appena si sentiva vicino a cadere, affidava a un successore il suo povero testimone: un cimelio, un trucco, un nomignolo. Così da vent'anni il Gran Magro continuava a esser chiamato il Gran Magro, dopo ch'erano morti in venti, insegnandoselo prima di morire.

Il Gran Magro è un medico del sanatorio per malati tubercolosi della Rocca, dov'è ricoverato l'io narrante.

Ho cercato "pretendere" e "staffetta" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "pretendendo alla nobiltà di una staffetta di lampade" in questo testo. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 2):

In attesa di qualcuno con informazioni più salde, formulo un'ipotesi. Chiaramente la parte poco chiara è la “staffetta di lampade”. “Pretendere alla nobiltà di XXX”, anche se non molto colloquiale, significa, più o meno, “aspirare a essere/fare qualcosa di nobile come XXX”.

Sulla “staffetta di lampade” congetturo che Bufalino intenda qualcosa come una serie di fuochi di segnalazione ognuno dei quali viene acceso quando si scorge l'accensione del precedente. In genere “staffetta”, oltre ai sensi letterali di corriere per lo più militare (che qui non è del tutto estraneo), e di tipo di gara atletica a squadre in cui ogni corridore parte quando viene raggiunto dal compagno precedente, si usa spesso per indicare un avvicendarsi, in genere previsto e pacifico, di persone o eventi: un dirigente che prende il posto del suo predecessore e simili.

L'unico conforto concreto che trovo a questa mia ipotesi è qualche menzione in rete di una “staffetta di luci”, che si riferisce a un passo del Talmud, e più precisamente alla mishnà relativa a Rosh haShanà, 2:2-4, in cui si spiega come si usassero delle fiaccole accese in cima a una serie di monti, come segnali luminosi per comunicare a distanza l'inizio del nuovo mese. (Si può trovare in ebraico e in inglese [qui](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.2?lang=bi).)

Non ho idea se Bufalino avesse dimestichezza con le antiche tradizioni ebraiche, ma situazioni simili si ritrovano anche in altri ambiti, sempre ammantati di una certa aura mistica,  dalle antiche [lampadedromie](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampadedromie_napoletane) fino a un episodio del *Signore degli anelli* di Tolkien.

<sub>Grazie per le segnalazioni a Riccardo De Contardi e a Charo.</sub>

Comment: C'era anche nel libro di Tolkien.

Comment: Potrebbe trattarsi di una [lampadedromia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/piazza-armerina_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27-Arte-Antica%29/)? Cioè, qualcosa di simile a [quello che si spiega qui](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampadedromie_napoletane)? O [anche qui](http://kids.bo.cnr.it/irrsaeer/ipersport/origini.html). Sospetto che Bufalino avesse più dimestichezza con il mondo classico che con le antiche tradizioni ebraiche. Infatti, nel libro ci sono alcuni riferimenti alla mitologia greca.

Comment: Senz'altro, @Charo, grazie per la segnalazione. Ne aggiungo un accenno nella risposta, per completezza.